# Is there a logic flow problem in my solution?

Tags: java, methods, while-loop, logic

I am a very new student. I have a coding exercise that I've been trying to get through, and I thought my solution was functional, but I am getting unexpected results. I'm wondering if there is a problem with my logic?

> **Assignment:** Write a method named sumFirstAndLastDigit with one parameter of type int called number.
>
> The method needs to find the first and the last digit of the parameter
>   number passed to the method, using a loop and return the sum of the
>   first and the last digit of that number.
>
> If the number is negative then the method needs to return -1 to
>   indicate an invalid value.
>   Example input/output
>
> - sumFirstAndLastDigit(252); → should return 4, the first digit is 2 and the last is 2 which gives us 2+2 and the sum is 4.
> - sumFirstAndLastDigit(257); → should return 9, the first digit is 2 and the last is 7 which gives us 2+7 and the sum is 9.
> - sumFirstAndLastDigit(0); → should return 0, the first digit and the last digit is 0 since we only have 1 digit, which gives us 0+0 and the
>     sum is 0.
> - sumFirstAndLastDigit(5); → should return 10, the first digit and the last digit is 5 since we only have 1 digit, which gives us 5+5 and the
>     sum is 10.
> - sumFirstAndLastDigit(-10); → should return -1, since the parameter is negative and needs to be positive.
>
> NOTE: The method sumFirstAndLastDigit needs to be defined as public
>   static like we have been doing so far in the course.
>
> NOTE: Do not add a  main method to solution code.

Here is what I came up with (I've included just the method itself):

```
public static int sumFirstAndLastDigit (int number) {

    if (number < 0) {
    return -1;
} else if (number <= 9) {
    number += number;
    return number;
}

int num = number;           
int sumFirstAndLast = 0;    

while (num > 0) {
    int useDigit = (num % 10);

    if ((num == number) || ((double)num < 1)) {
        sumFirstAndLast += useDigit;
    }
    num = num / 10;
} return sumFirstAndLast;
}
```

I **think** the issue might be the if statement in my while loop - but I'm not sure. I want it to check if num is equal to the original number that gets passed to the method, and check after num has been run through the while loop a few times, check if it's less than 1 (which is why I cast it as a double)

When I write out how each loop should run, it seems like it would work, but I've been getting incorrect output.

Any help, critiques, rules of thumb, etc. are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
public static int sumFirstAndLastDigit (int number) {
        int first = number; 
        while (first >= 10) {
            first /= 10;
        } 

        int last = number % 10;
        return (first + last) >= 0 ? (first + last) : -1;
    }
```

It gets frist and last number from the input and sums them together, then in the return you check if it was a negative number, then you return -1.